# How to fix "astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime"

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, debian

Is possible to get a specific problem with Debian OS to use astimezone() ?
I use the same code in Python 3 with both OS : Ubuntu and Debian.

The first is OK to use

The second get an error with the same instruction

LOCAL_TIMEZONE = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().tzinfo

debian error :
"ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime"

ubuntu works well

If there is anyone else that faced this and know what it is just reading what is here, well, would be nice if you tell me, I would be glad.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: i've never used DebianOS but have you checked if the OS has a timezone setting? Python takes the system timezone when the `.astimezone()` method gets called

Answer (score 0):

I'm on Ubuntu and I get same error, on Python 3.5.
I think it's something in system locale settings. 
`pytz` can solve this, but simpler solutions might exist:

```
import datetime as dt
import pytz

t = dt.datetime.now()
local_tz = pytz.timezone("Europe/Rome")

>>> print(local_tz.localize(t))
2019-05-31 12:09:48.199220+02:00

>>> print(local_tz.localize(t).tzinfo)
Europe/Rome

>>> print(local_tz.localize(t).astimezone(pytz.UTC))
2019-05-31 10:09:48.199220+00:00
```